# Splashscreen.hide() is not working in ios device

Tags: ios, react-native, error-handling, splash-screen

I'm using react-native-splash-screen library, Splashscreen.hide() is working properly for the android devices but its not working in ios devices because splashscreen is not hiding.

This is my appdelegate file

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"  // here

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  self.moduleName = @"spengucomputercourse";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  [RNSplashScreen show];  // here
  return YES;
}
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}
@end
```

Here is my app.js file where i am using hide function

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

import Navigations from './src/Routes/Navigations';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import {LogBox} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();
  useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, []);

  return <Navigations />;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to the version of react-native, I had the same problem, this link helped me [enter link description here](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/606#issuecomment-1401875339)

example:

```html
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"testApp";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  
  bool didFinish=[super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  
  [RNSplashScreen show];  // here
  return didFinish;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Now it's working fine. Your help is appreciable.